# Where can I find a C++ csound tutorial?

Tags: c++, audio, csound

I have just discovered csound and installed its C++ bindings.

The API is documented here (after a usual installation on Linux):

```
/usr/share/doc/libcsound64-doc/html/index.html
```

However, what I am missing is a good tutorial to get me started with the API.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of tutorials here: http://www.csounds.com/tootsother/index.html

Comment: None of the tutorial you link to are relevant to the c++ API. @Drakosha and @Paul R : why couldn't you create the csound tag? I can't do it myself.

Comment: @Drakosha: thank you for the down vote. Yes I did try to google it, but google interprets "C++" as simply "C" which comes often in many result as representing the musical note C. Google is not the answer to everything.

Comment: @Job: Thank you for creating the new tag :)

Comment: Try using "c++", with the double quotation marks. This way Google won't misinterpret it as C.

Comment: There appears to be a serious lack of information for csound / c++ ! Do let us know if you find anything, as I'm struggling with the same issue at the moment...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's an introduction to C API (pdf)](http://www.csounds.com/articles/RoryWalsh_CsoundAPI.pdf), which is practically the same as the C++ API. There are also a few examples in the Csound source code in the examples and frontends folders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for csound itself. To welcome you at S.O., here is a gift of your first 25 points. :)